# DropDownListFor a collection not selecting value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a strongly typed view with a custom viewmodel. This viewmodel contains a collection of books.

```
public IList<Books> Books { get; private set; }
```

I'm also passing a select-list to the view. However the `DropDownListFor` helper class doesn't automatically preselect the default value of the book.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Books[i].AuthorID, Model.Author as SelectList)
```

Everything else works, e.g. it does pass the selected value back to the controller.

I figured out a workaround by creating the select list in the viewmodel:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Books[i].AuthorID, new SelectList(Model.AuthorList, "Value", "Text", @Model.Books[i].AuthorID.ToString()))
```

However I don't want to implement this workaround if there is a simpler solution. is there a way that the view can handle values from a collection?

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Did you find why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be passing the list of authors as part of your model as you have in your workaround.  You can generate the select list in the controller however, it isn't a requirement to create the list in the view.  Something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Books[i].AuthorID, Model.AuthorList)
```

This would work if you create the list in the controller:

```
var model = new ViewModel()
{
    AuthorList = new SelectList(Model.AuthorList, "Value", "Text"),
};
```

And it will handle setting the selected item on it's own.

As for why your `Model.Author as SelectList` isn't working, I'm guessing Model.Author is not a list of author names and IDs.  It's probably a domain object and casting it using `as` is returning null.